# Integrating Samsung Smart TV SDK with Eclipse Juno (or newer)

Tags: eclipse, samsung-smart-tv

Samsung Apps Developer Forum ships with Eclipse-based IDE, however even 4.0 beta version is based on Eclipse Indigo. Is it possible to integrate Samsung Smart TV SDK with newer versions, like Juno?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible! Follow instructions from [blog.wirone.info](http://blog.wirone.info/2012/11/26/integracja-samsung-smart-tv-sdk-z-eclipse-juno-lub-nowszym/).

All we have to do is:

1. Download [Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary](https://web.archive.org/web/20130413071514/http://download.eclipse.org:80/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.2-201206081400/#PlatformRuntime) (Eclipse without plugins) and unpack it to target directory (we can change the name, let's say to "Eclipse Juno"). We will name it Juno below.
2. Install to Juno features that are installed in Samsung's SDK eclipse version. You can compare those with *Help → About Eclipse → Installation Details → Features* (or *Window → Preferences → Install/Update → "Uninstall or update software that is already installed" → Features*). Most of them are under "*Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development*" category. These features are (grouped by provider):

   - Eclipse Packaging Project

     - Javascript IDE
     - Marketplace Client (optional)
   - Eclipse Web Platform Tools

     - Eclipse Faceted Project Framework
     - Eclipse JavaScript Development Tools
     - Eclipse Web Developer Tools
     - Eclipse XML Editors and Tools
     - Eclipse XPath 2 Developers Tools
     - Eclipse XSL Developer Tools
   - Eclipse.org

     - Eclipse CVS Client
3. Javascript IDE listed above can't be installed via built-in tools, so we have to "steal" it from Samsung's IDE. Just copy/paste this directories to Juno:

   - plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript_1.4.2.20120131-1457
   - features/org.eclipse.epp.package.common.feature_1.4.2.20120213-0814
   - features/org.eclipse.epp.package.javascript.feature_1.4.2.20120213-0814

   Now you should have:
   [image: Features]
   <sub>(source: [wirone.info](http://static.blog.wirone.info/2012/11/Eclipse_Juno_with_features_from_Samsung_SDK.png))</sub>
4. Install Eclipse Graphical Modeling Framework (GMF) Runtime - it's needed for dependencies. Otherwise you wil get:

   > ```
   > ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2012-11-25 00:33:56.606
   > MESSAGE Problems resolving provisioning plan.
   > SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2012-11-25 00:33:56.606
   > MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from tv.samsung.sdk.core 2.1.1.201209271345 to bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.common.core 0.0.0.
   > ```
5. Close Juno.
6. Copy/paste `dropins/sec_smart_tv_sdk` directory from SDK 4.0 to Juno
7. Run Juno as administrator. There should be Samsung's SDK in menu bar.
   [image: Eclipse Juno with Samsung Smart TV SDK]
   <sub>(source: [wirone.info](http://static.blog.wirone.info/2012/11/Eclipse_4.2_with_Samsung_Smart_TV_SDK.png))</sub>
8. Open *Samsung Smart TV SDK → Samsung Smart TV SDK Preferences* - Oops, "SDK install path was not found", so select directory with SDK 4.0
9. Have a good developing :)

---

If you have a problem with integration, you can debug dropin installation. Create `.options` file in Juno's root directory and put in file:

> ```
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/debug=true
> org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core/reconciler=true
> ```

Run Juno with debug from console: `eclipse.exe -debug` and watch the logs. You can read about dropins [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21428463).

Might be helpful:

- Clearing `sec_smart_tv_sdk` entries in `Juno\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\...\data\cache.timestamps` where `...` is a random number, so just find `cache.timestamps` using system's search.
- Workspace's log (`.metadata/.log`)

Comment: What about the debugger for this IDE?

Comment: What 'debugger' do you mean?